# Display data from multiple Column to Multiple Rows in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a custom Records which has  follwing Columns. 
`Father First name, Father Last name, Father Email, Father Cell,`
`Mother First name, Mother last name, Mother Email, Mother Cell`
`Guardian FirstName, Guardian Lastname, Guardian Email, Guardian Cell`

All the above data's are stored in single rows. I have a task to display the data in Multiple Rows. I'm using data table, not sure we have any other way to achieve this. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
<lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={parameters} columns={columns}
                                    draft-values={draftValues} hide-checkbox-column="true" resize-column-disabled="true">   </lightning-datatable>
```

Js:

```
 const COLS = [
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'Father_First_Name__c', editable: false },
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'Father_Last_Name__c', editable: false },
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'Father_Email__c', editable: false },
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'Father_Cell__c', editable: false }
];  

@wire(getParentGuardian,{EnrollmentId : "dd"})

enroll(result){
this.wiredDataResult = result;
if (result.data) {
    this.parameters  = result.data;
    this.error = undefined;         
    } else if (result.error) {
    this.error = result.error;
    this.parameters  = undefined;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing  class GetParentGuardianController {

 @AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
public static List<Enrollment__c> getParentGuardian(String EnrollmentId) {
    system.debug('ENROL ' + EnrollmentId);
    return [Select Id, Father_First_Name__c, Father_Last_Name__c, Father_Email__c, Father_Cell__c,
            Mother_First_Name__c, Mother_Last_Name__c, Mother_Email__c, Mother_Cell__c
            from Enrollment__c WHERE Name=: 'E0008'];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to display same record in different rows, something below.

```
First Name | Last Name | Email | Cell
#1 row
#2 row
```

create cols in JS i.e

```
 const COLS = [
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'firstName', editable: false },
{ label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'lastName', editable: false },
{ label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', editable: false },
{ label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'cell', editable: false }
];
```

**Option 1**

create wrapper class in apex i.e

```
class data{
 String FirstName;
 String LastName;
 String Email;
 String Phone;
}
```

use this wrapper class to bind the data, for loop-through to SOQL. i.e

```
for (  Enrollment__c obj : [Select Id, Father_First_Name__c, Father_Last_Name__c from Enrollment__c WHERE Name=: 'E0008'] ){
data.add(obj.Father_First_Name__c,obj.Father_Last_Name__c,obj.Father_Email__c,obj.Father_Cell__c);
#same to add for mother row.
....
....
}
```

**Option 2**

You can achieve also to create Object in JS i.e

```
    let data = []
    response.data.map(val =>{ 
    data.push({'firstName' : val.Father_First_Name__c, 'lastName' :val.Father_Last_Name__c ...})
   //for mother
   data.push()
   //other
   data.push()
    })
```

Comment: how can we iterate the data in table ? Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

To Iterate data in table :

```
 lwcMethodName(){

    apexClassMethodName({}).then(data => {

        if(data){

            console.log("data= "+JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'))

            for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) { //data is been iterated

                const rec = data[i]; /*data at i index is allocated to rec 
                                         for easy access*/

                /*assigning data in json format to the specific column names 
                  as per table*/

                const tempjson = {name: (i+1).toString(), 

                    Id: rec.Id,

                    subject: rec.Subject,

                    assigned: rec.Owner.Name,

                    priority: rec.Priority,

                    status: rec.Status

                }

                dataTableData.push(tempjson)

            }

        }

    }).catch(error => {

        console.error("#**** error="+error)

    })

}
```